# [Talend]How to define a global filed in a talend job

Tags: talend

i create a talend job named aaa.
talend will auto create code like:

```
public class aaa { 
     ...
     ...
     // TODO i want define a field
     private String name = "test";
}
```

how can i implement to define field name?
ps: i don't want to use context or globalMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define  a *Routine*, call it *VALUES*. In the VALUES routine, define your values in public static field.

```
package routines;

public class VALUES {
   public static String fubar="Hello World";
}
```

then in others components, you make a reference to the fubar field with `VALUES.fubar`

Comment: thanks, routine is work. but i feel it's not best way to solve this question.

Comment: @ming if you refuse to use context variables, this answer is the only other way to make global variables in talend, by which I mean variables that can be passed to subjobs.